# Is it possible to edit scripts on a website using bookmarklets?

Tags: bookmarklet

I am trying to edit a script on a website, but I currently don't have access to inspect element and need to use bookmarklets. Is is possible to edit scripts on a website using bookmarklets?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by "edit a script"? A bookmarklet can only ever run after the page is already open, so you won't be able to change any behavoir of the script. You can still do anything you could do by running some javascript on the site though